# Count multiple row entries in excel

Tags: excel, count, conditional-statements

I'm trying to count the number of entries per row on an excel sheet. The formula should count the number of entries including and above the current row, but should count each value individually. Like this: Banana appears four times; thus, it will print 1 on A1, 2 on A3, 3 on A4, and 4 on A8.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
        A           B (expected result)
1   Banana          1   (Count all the entries "Banana" from A1:A1)
2   Apple           1   (Count all the entries "Apple" from A1:A2)
3   Banana          2   (Count all the entries "Banana" from A1:A3)
4   Banana          3   (Count all the entries "Banana" from A1:A4)
5   Apple           2   (Count all the entries "Apple" from A1:A5)
6   Apple           3   (Count all the entries "Apple" from A1:A6)
7   Cherry          1   (Count all the entries "Cherry" from A1:A7)
8   Banana          4   (Count all the entries "Banana" from A1:A8)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's dangerous to go alone, take this!

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)
```

Input this formula into `B1` and drag it down.

Answer (score 0):

Type the formula in Column C You will get what you are expecting

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I was over-complicating everything! :)